# SQL Statement (INNER JOIN ?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables wnews and categories.

I wanna print the names of categories by id

something like wnews.category (is an integer) and categories (id, name) where
wnews.category = cateroies.id and print name

I made something but I failde ...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT wnews.id, wnews.torrentid, wnews.title,
                             wnews.img, wnews.added, wnews.category,
                             wnews.genre, wnews.uploader, wnews.description,
                             categories.id, categories.name
                      FROM wnews
                        INNER JOIN categories
                          ON wnews.category=categories.id 
                      ORDER BY wnews.added DESC")
         or sqlerr();

while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{ printNews($arr["wnews.torrentid"], $arr["wnews.title"], 
            $arr["wnews.img"],       $arr["wnews.added"],
            $arr["categories.name"], $arr["wnews.genre"], 
            $arr["wnews.uploader"],  $arr["wnews.description"]);
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Solved.

```
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT wnews.id, wnews.torrentid, wnews.title, wnews.img, wnews.added,
        wnews.category, wnews.genre, wnews.uploader, wnews.description, categories.id, categories.name AS cat_name FROM wnews
        LEFT JOIN categories ON wnews.category = categories.id
        ORDER BY wnews.added DESC") or die(mysql_error());
        while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            printNews($arr["torrentid"], $arr["title"], $arr["img"], $arr["added"], $arr["cat_name"], $arr["genre"], $arr["uploader"], $arr["description"]);
        }
```

Comment: Failed? What failed? You didn't get any results or got a SQL error. If you got the error, what does the error day?

Comment: the code above just starts a query.. did you actually add code to print the result?

Comment: Calling `mysql_query("SELECT ...")` will not print anything. Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
    printNews($arr["wnews.torrentid"], $arr["wnews.title"], $arr["wnews.img"], $arr["wnews.added"], $arr["categories.name"], $arr["wnews.genre"], $arr["wnews.uploader"], $arr["wnews.description"]);
   }

Comment: and a photo .. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/143/unledlvr.png/

Comment: What do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wnews` , `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wnews JOIN categories wnews.category=categories.id` show?

Comment: If you solve your own question, post it as an answer, do not edit your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I like using the MySQL Query Browser when creating complex sql statements (with inner joins and such).

You should be able to download it here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Shannon